# Launching a .Net winforms application interactively from a service

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, windows-services

Environment - VS2008, Vista SP1.

I have written a process management service which can launch applications either in session 0 or the interactive console (usually 1). Please note this is NOT the normal mode of operation, it's for in-house debug purposes only. In the field, these processes will be safely hidden away in session 0. Security concerns do not apply.

#### Clearly people aren't reading this: security concerns do not apply. We have dozens of existing server apps (NOT services) written like this. We're not about to completely revamp these applications, we just need to be able to get at their inbuilt debug dialogs when running release versions in-house. I already know all about the canonical solution and pipes etc. If it was acceptable to add remote interfaces into all these apps, that's what we'd be doing.

I use the following code to do this:

```
ZeroMemory (&sui, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
sui.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);
sui.wShowWindow = pTask->GetWinStartState() ;
sui.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW ;
ZeroMemory (&pi,sizeof(pi));

if (bInteractive)
{
   HANDLE  hToken = NULL;
   DWORD dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
   WTSQueryUserToken (dwSessionId, &hToken);
   sui.lpDesktop = TEXT("winsta0\\default"); 
   LPVOID  pEnv = NULL;
   DWORD dwCreationFlag = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
   HMODULE hModu = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Userenv.dll"));

   if (hModu )
   {
      if (CreateEnvironmentBlock (&pEnv, hToken, FALSE))
         dwCreationFlag |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;    
      else
         pEnv = NULL;
   }

   bCreatedOk = CreateProcessAsUser (hToken,
                                     NULL,
                                     (LPTSTR)(pTask->GetExeName()),
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     FALSE,
                                     dwCreationFlag,
                                     pEnv,
                                     NULL,
                                     &sui,
                                     &pi);
}
else
{
   bCreatedOk = CreateProcess (NULL, ... blah...);
}
```

This all works fine and I can run and monitor native processes both in the Vista service session and the console. Great. Cakes and ale for everyone.

So here's the problem. If I try to run a **winforms** (C#) app interactively like this, it appears to run, shows up in Process Explorer as running in session 1, but on the desktop... nada. No window appears at all. The process runs up and shuts down all fine, but no window ever appears. The exact same winform exe run from explorer also shows up in session 1, but this time appears on the desktop just fine.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the evident hysteria there is nothing wrong with launching an application from a service into an interactive session provided it is done with the **same privileges as the interactive user or lower**. Since you are launching as the interactive user there can be no privilege escalation.

What you are doing does work. I suspect that the issue has something to do with your STARTUPINFO struct. You appear to be creating your sui on the stack but you don't show what you are doing with it. Are you initializing it to all 0s, if not you may be getting some garbage from the stack that is causing the window not to show or to show at some co-ordinates off the screen.

Comment: I am zeroing out the sui, it's just above the code I clipped. I'll add it to the sample for everyone to see. Thanks for the rationality :-)

Comment: Native apps work fine, as observed in the question. I suspect it's just the .Net runtime being anal. We have no .Net server apps, so it's really just an exercise in curiosity for my own benefit...

Comment: So the exact same code works for native apps but not .Net apps? There's no possibility that you're getting a different value from GetWinStartState? I just whipped up a simplified version of this launching a .Net app from a .Net service and it worked fine. In theory there should be no difference...

Comment: ... between a .Net app and a native app as far as CreateProcessAsUser is concerned. This is intriguing. When I have a little more time later on I will look into this more closely, if you haven't figured it out by then.

Comment: BINGO - I retested with a small mod to sui, thanks to you. Oh boy this is dumb. When I was doing some testing I accidentally swapped the script files that drive my service. So it wasn't even trying to launch the .Net test app I was worrying about. Shoot.

Comment: "Oh boy this is dumb". If I had a dollar for every time I've said that about something I've done I'd be sipping margaritas in the sun instead of slipping on the ice every time I try to take two steps outdoors:-)

Comment: Oh - I think it got into the state where I could see the process on Process Explorer, but didn't get a window, because the original script file I *was* using had the window state set wrong. Technically your answer is spot-on, so I've marked it answered. Thanks.

Comment: I just realised that this means the .Net runtime actually respects the ShowWindow setting in STARTUPINFO. Wow. That must make it one of the 0.000001% of apps that do :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a word, "don't".

Services typically run with reduced privileges and NOT as the current user.  As such, in Vista+ they're not allowed to interact with the users desktop.  On top of all that, services get a null Window Station.

You used to be able to check a box that said something like "Allow to interact with the desktop" but not anymore.  It's bad practice.

Your best bet is to create a helper app that runs in the users context and communicates with the service via a named pipe, LRPC or a socket, then have your helper app launch the program for the user.  This is the way most anti-virus now works.

Also, read [this whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/vista/services.mspx) from Microsoft on the subject.  Services can't run in anything other than session 0.

NOTE: a little research seems to indicate that you need to duplicate the token using something like this:

```
DuplicateTokenEx(hTokenNew,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL,
    SecurityIdentification,TokenPrimary,&hTokenDup);
```

Comment: This is being done for debug purposes, not for normal operation. In the field, these processes will run in session 0. We only want to bring them up for viewing debug dialogs. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Read a little further in that thread - you'l find an MS engineer correcting that code. WTSQueryUserToken returns a primary token, so duplication isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're trying to break Session Isolation. Like Mystere Man said, I don't think it's the right thing to do.

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B165194&x=5&y=3 might be useful if you really want to do this. In the code sample over there, they seem to initialize more thing than you do.

---

**EDIT** If it's for debugging purposes, i-e VS 2008 step-in, just add a wait loop at the beginning, and launch VS with administrator rights. You can attach to your service process without encountering system isolation.

Comment: That's an interesting link, especially the part about GUI drawing failing. But if that were the problem, native mode apps would fail as well, and as I said, they work fine. The problem is just with .Net winforms apps.