# Scripting a GUI from within a Windows Service?

Tags: user-interface, windows-services, automation, autoit

I would like to automate a windows app that comes only with as a GUI app (no support for command-line). The automation itself is relatively straightforward with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/).

Yet, I am wondering, is-it possible to launch the Windows App from with a windows service (that would simply call the AutoIt script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if Auto-it can work with UAC, you will most likely run into Session Isolation troubles - i.e services and desktop don't mix and send messages to each other, unless explicitely coded to pass through it.

So it's possible, but it's not a piece of cake either.

You probably want to look at : [Launching a .Net winforms application interactively from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564829/launching-a-net-winforms-application-interactively-from-a-service/564874#564874)

Answer (score 1):

While not at all advised because of complications associated with Session 0 isolation in the latest versions of Windows, AutoIt scripts can certainly be invoked from a Windows Service. Please see [this page for a few sample scripts that work as expected when called from a Windows Service](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/AutoIt/).

Unfortunately though, not all of the AutoIt functions seem to work in Session 0. We ran into trouble with the "Win*" routines (WinActivate, WinExists) so you should probably avoid those if you can. And since the documentation does not highlight the problematic functions be sure test thoroughly!